# Rebinding Syntax of Numeric Literals with NoImplicitPrelude

Tags: haskell, syntax, ghc

It appears my understanding of the -XNoImplicitPrelude flag in ghci is wrong and I'm very confused about it.

The [documentation](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.3/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#rebindable-syntax) says

> An integer literal 368 means "fromInteger (368::Integer)", rather than "Prelude.fromInteger (368::Integer)".

However, when I load this code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoImplicitPrelude #-}
module Try where
import Prelude (Float,Integer, realToFrac)
data MyNum = Nummy Float
fromInteger :: Integer -> MyNum 
fromInteger x = Nummy (realToFrac x)
```

Into ghci, I get the following:

```
~/tmp$ ghci -XNoImplicitPrelude try.hs 
[1 of 1] Compiling Try              ( try.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Try.
*Try> 4
4
```

When I expect to get:

```
*Try> 4
Nummy 4.0
*Try>
```

Simliar things happen from within the Try module; for instance there is a type error when I declare a function return type MyNum and define it equal to an integer literal.

Answer (score 4):

The docs you linked to say that one has to enable the `RebindableSyntax` extension for that to work.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering why nobody else had asked this one. I think I need "RTFM" tattooed on the back of my hand.